# why most traits in org.apache.spark.ml.param.shared package are private

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-ml

I am developing an estimator and a model for specific spark.ml pipeline stage. I ended up looking into spark source code to see how current implementations looks like. I was wondering why most useful traits are private. I guess traits like HasInputCol, HasOutputCol, etc. can be used by custom implementations of estimators and models.

Comment: That is why you should use Python :) To be serious someone made that decision and we have to live with that for now (until 2.1.0?). For basics you can use `UnaryTransformer`. See also https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-7146

Comment: @zero323 thanks for the comment and the link.

Comment: I've just stumbled upon this problem. Very annoying. =)